# still not getting solution..please anyone help me?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i hava ddl and textbox..if my text box value already exist in ddl means i should display message as already exist in ddl..

i tried compare calidator..but not working,,,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmothertongue" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server"
          CssClass="dd_NoWidth" Width="136px" 
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlmothertongue_SelectedIndexChanged"
          AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
          DataTextField="mothertongue"
          DataValueField="mothertongue">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewMatrimonyConnectionString %>"
   SelectCommand="SELECT distinct  [mothertongue] FROM [tbl_mothertongue]union all select 'Others'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtmothertongue" runat="server" 
       Visible="False" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtmothertongue" runat="server" Visible="False"
       AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: So what is your problem here? Please be more specific!!

Comment: Your question is vague and incomplete. It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. For that reason I voted for it to be closed.

Comment: Please ask a real QUESTION in the topic.

Comment: so you want it in clientside or serverside?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not really supplying much data, I can just give you a solution with the data I have.

```
 if (ddl.items.Contains(value)) 
 {
       //show message it already contains item
 }
```